# Null answer from JSONArray in Android

Tags: php, android, sql, json

i have this PHP code, and a DataBase with "Question", "answer1", "answer2", "Question_id" well, when i make an SQL Query from PHP and encode the answer to send an Android app, ONLY the "Question" field is null, i read that it could be the code, but my DataBase is encoded in utf-8. I also try to convert the result to utf-8 with the "utf8_encode" function in PHP but it doesn't work, so i ask for some help :P

Here's the code (i deleted the code to conect to de DataBase and some un-used lines....)

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Questions");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$max_value = (int)$num_rows;
$quest_id = rand ( 1, $max_value);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE id_quest = $quest_id");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$output[]=$row;



    echo(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are slightly mistaken. Your database might be encoded in UTF8, but the communication from php to and from the database ***isn't*** (it's latin1 / ISO-8859-1 by default).

Unless you are doing a

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

somewhere that you didn't share with us, *that* is the solution you should be looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two queries try using just one. It may not fix the problem, but it reduces the number of calls to the db:

```
SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i've tried, but the problem still there, i don't have any experience with JSON but if all the Strings are encoded to utf-8 it should work....  but no hahahaha

Comment: Do you get anything from simply `echo $output`